# Why can't we call super class constructor using super keyword from child class method in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, try-catch, super

I am very new to java so I have little confusion on above title question.

Please can anybody help me to get this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: may be because you need an object instance before calling a method, even when you call a instance level method A inside instance method B, you are actually calling `this.A` from `this.B` ... see the implicit this ref

Comment: where super or this constructor are not available in `this` context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, each keyword has its own meaning ... for example to define a new class, we use 'class' keyword. Each keyword is reserved to do a particular thing. Basically when you type a keyword, it is an instruction to jvm and jvm knows what needs to be done on an encounter with a particular keyword. Same way super() is designed to be called with in a subclass constructor only so that when you instantiate object of subclass, super class defaults will also get instantiated. So it ensures that on instantiating a sub class instance, super class defaults will also get instantiated. Now, if you want to create a super class Object inside your method, you can use new keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following case:

```
class Father {
    Father() {}
}

class Son extends Father {
    Son() {
        super();
    }

    void foo() {
        super(); //won't compile
    }
}
```

You can write `Father f = new Father();` to construct a `Father`, but you can't illegally write `super f = super()`.

Otherwise two problems occur:

(1) what is `super`? How should the compiler compile the keyword `super`? If you further extends Son then the compiler may not be able to determine the actual class `super()` returns.

(2) the keyword `this` is ambiguous. Do you mean `this = super()` (similar to the use in constructor, but will be strange in this case), or do you want to create an instance of the superclass?

If you really want to dynamically obtain an instance, the most you can do is to use reflection:

```
try {
    Object o = this.getClass().getSuperclass().newInstance();
} catch (InstantiationException ex) {
} catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
}
```

But this appears to be dangerous. To conclude you should either use `Father f = new Father()` to create a `Father` instance, or use the keyword `this` to refer to the `Son` instance (which inherits all methods and fields from `Father`) directly.

Comment: Thanks.. it helped.